# How to parametrize Load Runner tests created with Java Record Replay protocol?

Tags: java, loadrunner, java-gui

Most of articles about HP Load Runner parametrization recommend to use `{param_name}` structure inside a string or `lr_eval_string("{param_name}")`.

Actually in Java protocol the first one still remains the string with param name but not with param value and the second one throws an error `"cannot find symbol ... symbol:   method lr_eval_string(String)"`

What is the correct way to parametrize HP LR script created with Java Record Replay protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `eval_string(String)` of `lr` object should be used, e.g.:

```
_hashtable1.put("java.naming.security.principal", lr.eval_string("{login}"));
```

BTW: there are lots of useful functions in object `lr`